# Importing a Sharepoint website from a .wsp - List X does not exist

Tags: 2010, solution-package, import

I'm a total noob in Sharepoint Development, but I'm quite skilled in .NET.

I need to deploy a ready-to-go website from two .wsp files:

- App.wsp
- AppEmployeeService.wsp

I suppose that `Lists` and other structures should be already present in these `.wsp` archives.

I got a command-line guide on how to import that and deploy:

```
• iisreset

• Add-SPSolution -LiteralPath "C:\App.wsp"

• Install-SPSolution -Identity "App.wsp" -WebApplication
"http://10.1.1.140" –GACDeployment

• Add-SPSolution -LiteralPath "C:\AppEmployeeService.wsp"

• Install-SPSolution -Identity "AppEmployeeService.wsp" -GACDeployment

• Enable-SPFeature –Identity APP_APP_Feature –url
"http://10.1.1.140”

• Disable-SPFeature –Identity "APP_APP_Feature" –url
http://10.1.1.140 –force

• Enable-SPFeature –Identity "APP_APP_Feature" –url
http://10.1.1.140 –force

• iisreset
```

But when I run 
`Enable-SPFeature –Identity APP_APP_Feature –url "http://10.1.1.140"`

I get an exception:

> Enable-SPFeature: List 'Employees' does not exist at site with URL
>   'http://10.1.1.140'

How does it work? Shouldn't it create these lists during import?

Answer (score 0):

Only if there is a feature built into the wsp to create the employee list when the feature is activated.  If not, I would look for a template for the Employee list.  If you just make a list called Employees, it might deploy, but more than likely will not work because of missing columns the custom solutions is looking for.  I would look through the code and see what the solution is using the Employee list for.  Create the Employee list, make a template out of it, and add the stp file for the template to your solution to build the list when the feature is activated (if a template does not already exist).  You can check if the list exist in the feature before creating it.

Comment: In the VS project, I have a EmployeeView in which I have ViewFields and FieldRefs with fields, which look like this list's column names. I suppose that this is the list.
Isn't it?

Comment: @Spectre That might just be a view, which doesn't create a list. There should be something in the feature installed/activated event that creates the list.  If not, then the feature assumes the list is already created.

Comment: The code assumes that the list is already created. I have to migrate the entire website and all it's features to the new Sharepoint enviroment which I created. If these lists were created in old Sharepoint, I'd need to export them manually, probably with .cmp files. Correct?